# How to log step sizes when using scipy.optimize.minimize (L-BFGS-B)?

Tags: python, logging, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am working with the L-BFGS-B implementation of the scipy.optimize.minimize package. I know that when using a gradient (i.e. using the argument *jac=...*), the algorithm computes the corresponding step size by line search (Wolfe-condition).

Does anyone know if there is a way to extract this step size from the algorithm or its results (to e.g. later store it in a csv-file)?